# Concert place name into lat/long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, maps

I'm wanting to do something with my application I have currently.

I currently have a bunch of events with names inside of places/venues

I'm wondering how I can get these places/venues to convert into lat/long for me to use elsewhere.

e.g. my data show I have Scarborough Open Air Theatre. How can I get the lat/long of this with only this bit of data?

I'm Using Rails

Sam

Comment: You can use a gem called Geocoder. It allows you to convert address to coordinates and vice versa. You can even convert to an address based off of an IP address. There is also a very detailed railscast episode on how to use the gem's feautes. You can check it out at https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder